# Could i change kernel configuration at real time?

Tags: kernel

I want to know if I can change kernel configuration at real time.
(.config)

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

if *realtime* means *while the kernel is running*: **no**

if *realtime* means *while I'm compiling the kernel*: **no**

The `.config` file is the configuration for the compilation process. So, you can modify it before start a new kernel compilation. Each time you modify the `.config` and you want see applied you modification, you have to re-compile the kernel.